# Performance Problems on Ubuntu with nvme harddisk

Tags: usb, performance, nvme

I have just installed a brand new HP Spectre x360 with Ubuntu 16.04.

When transfering big amounts of data the system load (as seen with glances) slowly rises up to 16. I see very high IOWait and after a while the system gets unresponsive.

The systems harddrive is a SSD : SAMSUNG MZVLV512HCJH-000H1 connected via PCIe.

Even when I copy the file on the harddrive (from on location to another on the same partition) I notice high system loads (up to 8) and high IOWaits (averaging 40% but rising up to 90% temporarily). I have not measured the actual transfer speed but it feels rather slow.

When another device is involved, it gets worse. I tried to copy via ethernet (using a USB ethernet adapter) using scp , I finally succeeded copying from a USB2.0 external harddrive and I experimented with an SDCard in the computers SDCard slot. In any of those cases the computer turned completely unresponsive. Exceuting a shell command (like ls) would take half a minute and even a ctrl-C to stop the transfering process would take ages.

Otherwise the computer is very responsive. In normal operation even loading big programs is very fast.

I have looked at NVME optimization. So far I have only added a noatime to the root partitions fstab entry. I have read that aligning the partition can be a factor but I am not aware of what alignment my harddrive would need. So far all I know about it is the output of nmve list which is :

```
Node             SN                   Model                                    Version  Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     S2CTNX0H511698       SAMSUNG MZVLV512HCJH-000H1               1.1      1         264.52  GB / 512.11  GB    512   B +  0 B   BXV72H0Q
```

Anybody has an idea what this problem is related to and how to solve it ?

Comment: Use `sudo fdisk -l` for a quick partition alignment check, and `sudo parted` align-check for a more precise check.

Comment: parted align-check says aligned.

Comment: gparted shows that my root partition starts on sector 1050624 which is a multiple of 2048.  Same for the EFI boot partion on sector 2048 and the swap partition on  966848512. I have read that SSD's might want an alignment on 4096 (whatever). So is a 2048 sector alignment ok or does it need to be 4096 sectors/ blocks or MiB ?

Comment: You might check for a firmware update for the Samsung SSD. My friend had a bunch that needed updates. How much RAM do you have? How much swap?

Comment: In the fdisk -l output, it'll tell you sector and I/O size. Older drives are 512/512... newer drives can be 512/4096 or even 4096/4096.

Comment: fdisk -l:  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes,
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes,
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes, 16 GB ram 16GB Swap, I will look for Firmware but then I have erased the Windows 10 from the compouter so I might not be able to apply a firmware update..

Comment: In your BIOS, is your disk settings for ACHI or something else like IDE?